# Python QT functions fromWinId and createWindowContainer not working on Linux

Tags: python, qt, pyside, embedding

I am developping a gui application on Python with PySide2. I'm using fromWinId and createWindowContainer functions to embed an external window app in my app. It's perfectly working on Windows, I can access my embedded app (Paint app for example). But on Linux, it's not working the same. I manage to get the window id of the external app and to embed it my app, but when it's embedded, I only have a frozen image of the external app.

This is my code :

```
import Xlib.display
from PySide2.QtGui import QWindow
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout


def _get_window_id_win32(title):
    import win32gui
    return win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)


def get_window_id_linux(name):
    display = Xlib.display.Display()
    root = display.screen().root
    window_ids =       root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom("_NET_CLIENT_LIST"), Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value
    for window_id in window_ids:
        window = display.create_resource_object("window", window_id)
        window_name = window.get_wm_name()
        if window_name and name in window_name:
            return window_id


def run_app(window_id):
    app = QApplication([])

    main = QMainWindow()
    widget_central = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    button = QPushButton()
    button.setText('CLICK')
    layout.addWidget(button)

    window = QWindow.fromWinId(window_id)
    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(window)
    layout.addWidget(widget)

    widget_central.setLayout(layout)
    main.setCentralWidget(widget_central)
    main.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window_id = get_window_id_linux("Window Title") # REPLACE 'Window Title' by the title of the window you want to embed
    # window_id = _get_window_id_win32('Window Title') IF YOU WANT TO TEST ON WINDOWS
    if window_id:
        run_app(window_id)
```

Comment: In this era of different window managers and compositors(Wayland for example), embedding some random X11 window is not fully supported anymore. That's why Gnome devs had invented GtkSocket/GtkPlug in Gtk2 and dropped them in Gtk4.

Comment: So that's mean that today we don't have any way to embed a X11 window in another app on Linux ?

Comment: It depends on the environment. It may work if you use a classical window manager and don't use Wayland.

Comment: When I run "echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"" on my Linux, I get "x11". So for me, it's not Wayland. Am I right ?

Comment: @claire-c that's not really the point: the fact is that nowadays more and more people is using Wayland, meaning that your program will probably fail in those cases: even if X11 programs can work on Wayland, they can often have issues with input or drawing, and since X embedding is already quite buggy on its own, that would make things even worse.

Comment: @claire-c yes you are using XOrg. I'm also using XOrg in Ubuntu 20.04, and the embedding does not work properly.